# $N$ Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ and fixed $a>1$ calculate: $\lim \frac{\mathbb{P}(N\geq k)}{\mathbb{P}(N=k)}$

Tags: probability-theory

For $N$ Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ and fixed $a>1$ calculate:
\begin{equation}
            \lim \frac{\mathbb{P}(N\geq k)}{\mathbb{P}(N=k)},
        \end{equation}

$\lambda \rightarrow \infty, k \rightarrow \infty, k/\lambda \rightarrow a$.

I'm thinking we can compute:
\begin{align}
            \frac{\mathbb{P}(N\geq k)}{\mathbb{P}(N=k)} &= \frac{\sum_{i = k}^\infty \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}}{\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}}\\
            &= \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^i k!}{(i+k)!}
 \end{align}

But I'm not sure how to simplify the last sum. Some hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: upper bound the infinite sum with a geometric series.

Comment: the upper bound gives $\frac{a}{a-1}$. But how do I show this is a lower bound as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As you noted, the ratio is at most $a/(a-1)$. You can prove a matching lower bound, this time using a finite geometric series.
For any $N$,

$$
    \sum_{i\ge 0}\lambda^i\frac{k!}{(k+i)!}
\ge \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\lambda^i\frac{k!}{(k+i)!}
\ge \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{\lambda^i}{(k+N)^i}
=   \frac{1-(\lambda/(k+N))^N}{1-\lambda/(k+N)}
$$
As long $N$ is not too large compared to $\lambda$ and $k$, then $\lambda/(k+N)\sim 1/a$, so the above is $\sim (1-a^{-N})/(1-a^{-1})$. Furthermore, as long as $N\to\infty$, the $a^{-N}$ will disappear. I will leave the details to you.